# Android Firebase: Retrieve ID

Tags: android, json, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to get the ID of the item "001" in the firebase database. I have made this database manually

```
 "movies" : {
    "action" : {
      "001" : {
                "name" :    "Firebase",
                "director": "Google"  
              }
               }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firebase store data in json format which is represented as key-pair value.

So if you want to retrive item "001" which represents a key in your data structure.

To get "001" you can use Firebase addListenerForSingleValueEvent .

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("movies").child("action");
mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    HashMap mapRecord = (HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    Iterator listKey = mapRecord.keySet().iterator();
                    while (listKey.hasNext()) {
                        String id = listKey.next().toString();
                   //you get you key here    
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: you're missing the `001` from the JSON model in your code. I'd also recommend not converting to a map, but instead use `dataSnapshot.getChild("name").getValue(String.class)` to get the properties.